# Why did these two pairs of characters look physically identical in completely different times?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-picard

In *Star Trek: Picard,*

> Picard & Friends travel back into the past yet again and meet a "Supervisor" named Tallinn who is watching over Renée Picard. We also learn several episodes later that Kore Soong is the product of Dr. Adam Soong's illegal genetic experiments.

It turns out that Tallinn looks physically identical to Laris and Soji looks exactly like Kore. How is this possible? Is Laris a descendent of Tallinn? Is Soji based on Kore somehow?

Comment: There's just no way to explain this in universe.  The real answer is somewhere between "they really liked the actor" and "she already had a contract".  They did essentially the same thing with Isa Briones too.

Comment: Given that Q's there, it's quite possible that the entire "back in time" nonsense is a Q fantasy world. Like Sherwood forest, but a bit more elaborate

Comment: @ThePopMachine But in-universe, is there any reason why?

Comment: https://screenrant.com/star-trek-picard-watcher-tallinn-laris-story-impact/ - Maybe. It remains to be seen

Comment: I've updated the question to include Kore Soong.

Comment: This is an example of quantum entanglement through multiple dimensions and timelines.

Comment: While you're at it, it is fascinating how a Romulan commander looks almost exactly like....Spock's father, Sarek :-)

Comment: Furthermore, I think partly it may be the third explanation "the producer/showrunner is a chicken about having to sit down and fire someone so they avoid it at all costs even if it doesn't make sense".

Comment: I don't know if it deserve and answer, but regarding Tallin/Laris, there is still the possibily that after inevitable Picard death (from age if nothing else), Laris will rejoin the supervisors and that they are in fact the same person.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the [Identical Grandson](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/IdenticalGrandson) trope, a trope that Star Trek is very fond of.

Picard mentions that Tallinn is an ancestor of Laris. Soji is modelled after Data's painting, "Daughter", and [Memory Alpha assumes](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Soji_Asha) that this painting was inspired by Kore and her sisters.

- Lieutenant Worf looks like his grandfather:

[image: Lieutentant Worf]
[image: Colonel Worf]

- Picard looks like his ancestor:

[image: Jean Luc Picard]
[image: Ancestor of Picard]

- Janeway looks like her ancestor:

[image: Kathryn Janeway]
[image: Shannon O'Donnel]

- Tasha Yar looks like her (half-romulan) daughter

[image: Tasha Yar]
[image: Sela]

- Kirk looks like his brother:

[image: James Kirk]
[image: Kirks Brother]

- Don't get me started on Data

Comment: T'Pol and her grandmother